# What should we do with a tag that's used only for questions closed as off-topic but not deleted?

Tags: discussion, scope, tags, retagging

I just discovered that we have a [james-bond](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/james-bond) tag.

This surprised me, as community consensus is that James Bond is off-topic. So I went to burninate the tag ... and discovered that it's used on two questions, [one of which](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/77028/is-james-bond-explicitly-described-as-caucasian-in-ian-flemings-books) is closed for not being about SFF while [the other](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/75798/how-implausible-is-the-landing-of-spectres-spacejacking-in-you-only-live-twice) will probably soon be closed for asking about real-world science (I just cast the first VTC). But both these questions have positively-scored answers and are unlikely to be deleted.

What should we do?

- If we get rid of the tag, how do we retag those two questions?
- If we leave the tag, will its existence make people think James Bond is on-topic?

Comment: BTW, why aren't/weren't they migrated? Was it before movies.SE graduated?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Not sure; I can't remember when M&TV did graduate. One of them is marked as "migration rejected" from Space.SE.

Comment: why isn't James Bond science fiction?

Comment: @user13267 Don't ask me; I wasn't around when that consensus was made. There's probably a meta post about it somewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not particularly happy about it but [james-bond](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/james-bond) probably needs to stay.

In particular, our consensus on scope is that if someone asked a question specifically about some futuristic technology *in* a *James Bond* movie, that would probably be on topic. So, there's a possibility we'll need the tag later.

I've edited the tag wiki to make it clarify the proper usage of the tag.

While we do need to keep an eye on this tag, to make sure it doesn't get used on any on-topic questions, it's otherwise serving a purpose.

Answer (score 3):

**I’d let the [james-bond](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/james-bond) tag survive.**

- It’s an appropriate tag for the two questions.
- It would be hard to argue “it’s on-topic because there’s a tag for it” when the only two questions in that tag have been closed for being off-topic.